# How can I cover the upper part of my nose to avoid UV radiations?

Tags: health, uv-protection, sun

I use hat + hood + sunglasses + [neck gaiter](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B07PLTZJBH/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) + UV umbrella to fully covered my face when going outside if too much sun. The problem is the upper part of my nose is not fully covered, e.g.:

[image]

Larger pics:

[image] [image]

([image source 1](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-american-army-in-iraq-reenactment-soldier-with-sunglasses-and-face-87075349.html) ; [image source 2](https://www.tribuneindia.com/news/archive/ludhiana/ban-on-covering-faces-while-driving-gets-thumbs-down-122348))

How can I cover the upper part of my nose to avoid UV radiations?

---

Answers to comments:

> - a bigger hat and sunscreen? – [njzk2](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/4154/njzk2) [1 min ago](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/27268/how-can-i-cover-the-upper-part-of-my-nose-to-avoid-uv-radiations?noredirect=1#comment67777_27268)

Sunscreen is temporary. Also, inconvenient + need to carry sunscreen bottle + easy to not properly applied it etc. Also given the position, I fear sunscreen may get partially removed when moving neck gaiter or sunglasses. A hat doesn't block reflective UVs.

Comment: Various glacier glasses I’ve owned have a nose shield to go with the side shields. Google ‘glacier glasses nose shield’

Comment: a bigger hat and sunscreen?

Comment: @njzk2 sunscreen is temporary. Hat doesn't block reflective UVs.

Comment: both valid points. Sun screen needs to be re-applied regularly. I assume that's a problem?

Comment: @njzk2 yes (inconvenient + need to carry  sunscreen bottle + easy to not properly applied it etc.). Also given the position, I fear sunscreen may get partially removed when moving neck gaiter or sunglasses.

Comment: How is such a breath-obstructing neck gaiter not more inconvenient than taking a small tube of sunscreen with you, and re-applying it after a while?

Comment: @leftaroundabout my neck gaiter is not breath-obstructing.

Comment: Is night-time an option for you?  Or at least avoiding the 1000-1600 window ?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt if it's thin enough not to obstruct your breath then it probably also provides less UV protection than sunscreen would.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I've walked in the death valley in the summer or uyuni desert while 100% sunny without any sunburn.

Comment: @Criggie I sometimes engage in diurnal activities

Comment: How about a strip of sports tape?

Comment: @spuck thanks good idea you're welcome to add it as answer

Comment: Proper glacier goggles generally come with a nosepiece and side guards, and often are darker to UV than mass-market sunglasses.

Answer (score 15):

As skin cancer is such a major issue in Australia, there is a huge range of products that shield the nose.

From the [Australian Cancer Council](https://www.cancercouncilshop.org.au/products/nose-guard), see this one which clips onto your sunglasses as an example.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

**Zinc Oxide Paste**

Surfers use zinc oxide for the most burnable areas of the face, and it might work for you too.

It's an opaque white paste that totally blocks harmful UV. It's not greasy like sunscreen, and it won't run when you sweat. A little dab on your exposed areas should keep them safe.

[image: Dude in sunglasses with zinc oxide on his face]

Comment: Thanks, the UV-B protection provided by the  zinc oxide  sounds suboptimal according to https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3482794/: "Smaller, micronized zinc oxide is considered as a broad-spectrum UV protectant. Although not as efficient in the UVB range as titanium dioxide, this inorganic UV filter covers predominately the UVA spectra, with protection into UVA1. Zinc oxide is also considered inferior as a UV filter to the organic sunscreens.\[[12](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3482794/#ref12)\]"

Comment: Don't go with the older [lead-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venetian_ceruse) alternative though.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I believe that's referring to micronized zinc oxide, which has been broken down into tiny micro- or nano-particles so it will go on clear. It's usually used as one of several active ingredients. What I'm suggesting is non-micronized zinc in at least 25% concentration that stays opaque. It's the stuff in diaper cream (although diaper cream is not FDA approved as sunscreen). Some commercial brands are Surfmud and Zinka (which comes in fun colors).

Comment: @Robert Thanks, good point, I think you're right https://www.badgerbalm.com/pages/broad-spectrum-uva-sunscreen-protection "Zinc oxide is the only single active ingredient that offers excellent protection from UVA and UVB rays." Do you know why diaper cream is not FDA approved as sunscreen?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Some have additives that would make them less effective or unpleasant (e.g. fish oil), others have insufficient concentration of zinc, and there may be other reasons. But even if they would pass, testing and certification is expensive. If it's not being marketed as a sunscreen it would be a waste. I have used it in the distant past and it seemed to work fine, but now I go for something tested and certified.

Answer (score 9):

Ski goggles.  They're made for just that - blocking UV - and allow you to wear prescription glasses underneath.

Did just this on several summer cycling and kayak trips.  All day in full sun ones, including pulling into Forks, WA at 95F on the city thermometer after an 80k ride.  With glasses.  Whatever unpleasantness was going on, the goggles weren't a big part of things.  Goggles allow you to limit sunscreen to really your lower face and neck.

Of course, you look like you're from Tatooine, but that's half the fun.

And, no, not advising them for a jog.  Or in any activity where you have a lot of up/down sudden acceleration causing them to move around.

Comment: not all ski goggles fit glasses underneath. You need to find ones specifically designed for that usage. Also, ski goggles tend to keep you warmer that regular sun glasses

Comment: @njzk2 -- Most ski goggles, these days, do fit over glasses.

Comment: @njzk2 It's pretty easy to see if goggles allow for glasses or not.  Try them on.  Re. the heat, I specifically gave examples of high-heat/high-exertion usage.  Not saying this works for everyone or all cases, but it worked very well for me.  YMMV.

Answer (score 7):

Thinking practically, how about just putting a bandaid on there? Or buying surfer’s sunblock that really sticks for a long time.

Comment: The bandaid worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Some face shields also include nose protection, [e.g.](https://bekogear.com/fantom/fantom-steele-blue/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210626175840/https://bekogear.com/fantom/fantom-steele-blue/)):

[image]

[image]

Another option is using a [UV face shield visor](https://smile.amazon.com/s?k=UV+face+shield+visor&ref=nb_sb_noss_2), [e.g.](https://smile.amazon.com/Face-Shield-Protector-Visor-Protection/dp/B08V6HTQ81/ref=sr_1_15?dchild=1&keywords=UV+face+shield+visor&qid=1624730877&sr=8-15) ([mirror](https://archive.ph/2021.06.26-181050/https://www.amazon.com/Face-Shield-Protector-Visor-Protection/dp/B08V6HTQ81/ref=sr_1_15?dchild=1&keywords=UV%2Bface%2Bshield%2Bvisor&qid=1624730877&sr=8-15&pldnSite=1&th=1)):

[image]

Good feedback on it in the comment  section:

> That fancy visor doesn't seem to be practical in a mild windy outdoor environment. – [Pere](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/11125/pere) 2 hours ago

Another option would be a [full face cover](https://smile.amazon.com/s?k=cagoule&crid=P7P8YH4EQ1R&sprefix=cagoul%2Caps%2C208&ref=nb_sb_noss_2):

[image]]

([image source](https://www.capitalxtra.com/artists/kanye-west/news/julia-fox-slams-claims-shes-dating-kanye-west-for-money/))

---

[Ben Crowell](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/2169/ben-crowell) claims most of us don't want to look that silly with a nose guard but I disagree, that looks rather neutral to me:

[image]

([image source](https://th.aliexpress.com/item/467419820.html))

---

Since comments can be removed rather arbitrarily on Stack Exchange, I'll copy below my warning regarding the [use of zinc oxide as UV protection](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/27274/2667):

> The UV-B protection provided by the zinc oxide sounds suboptimal according to https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3482794/: "Smaller, micronized zinc oxide is considered as a broad-spectrum UV protectant. Although not as efficient in the UVB range as titanium dioxide, this inorganic UV filter covers predominately the UVA spectra, with protection into UVA1. Zinc oxide is also considered inferior as a UV filter to the organic sunscreens.[[12](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3482794/#ref12)]"

Comment: Haha, you're the first person who made me laugh today :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be in an extremely bright environment, such as during all-day glacier travel, then you could consider a plastic shield like the one Rory Alsop describes. They work well. But most of the time, most of us don't want to look that silly or be that uncomfortable and encumbered.

An option that works well for me is to use a chapstick-type product that has a high SPF. It's convenient to carry in a pocket, it doesn't look weird, it doesn't run off when you sweat, and it doesn't get in your eyes.

Comment: @MartinF is that not a brand in your area? It clearly means "lip balm" to me

Comment: FWIW after so long (@MartinF and Kat) there are lip sunblock products packed like chapstick.  I've got factor 50, and have had lower factor.  The price per gram is high, but you'd be using very little, and it goes on well on normal skin.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use a small Band-Aid.  Easily removed when no longer needed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With a UV nose guard, as particularly used by mountaineers. There are lots on the market, expensively, just search for them.